# computes the length of side of a triangle

Tags: java, math, java.util.scanner

I need to write a complete program that computes the length of side of a triangle using the following formula:

```
 a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc cos(degree).
```

The length of sides `b`, `c`, and `degree` and giving by the user.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*; 
import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class testing {
  static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    double a, b, c, degree;

    System.out.println ("Enter B, C and degree");
    b = console.nextDouble();
    c = console.nextDouble();
    degree = console.nextDouble();

    a = sqrt(((b*b) + (c*c) - (2*b*c))*cos(degree));

    System.out.printf ("answer %.2f ",a);
  }
}
```

However, the answer is different from the one I solve on paper. If:

```
b = 4,  c= 7,  degree = 45
```

The program returns: `2.17`

My answer on paper: `5.03`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.cos()` accepts angles in radians, not degrees. You should convert the input angle to radians.

```
a = sqrt((b*b) + (c*c) - (2*b*c) * cos(toRadians(degree)));
```

This results in

```
5.0400416916483275
```

Comment: @HalahAl-Mazrou If this answer solved your problem.Then accept the answer by clicking on the right mark Beside the answer.